# register a copy of the process with windows registry for multi threading

Tags: multiprocessing, registry

I am trying to run a program that can only run on one core. I have a 12 core machine and I had this idea, possibly wrong, that I could maybe register the program multiple times with windows registry and convince windows that its 12 different programs and in the end run it on all cores.

Has anyone tried something like this before because I haven't been successful with this yet. The program I have has a lot of subkeys and is it possible to just copy the whole key structure instead of doing it one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into application virtualization.  Something like VMWare ThinApp would do what you want.  The additional overhead would be more than worth the simplicity of deployment IMO.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization